# CPU Overclock Frequency not Showing

Tags: cpufreq, overclocking

I've a Q9550 successfully overclocked @ 3,33 GHz which works fine on windows and in ubuntu 16.04 too since several years.

The problem is that I've recently installed concky and discovered that my maximum speed is the stock cpu speed (2.83) instead of 3.33 when cpu is under stress conditions when I run ubuntu.

I've read a plethora of documentation on this, but found no definite solution. I do not want the cpu to work at maximum speed all the time and therefore altering the ondemand thing. I just want it to run at maximum speed when requested like it does in windows.

I'm stuck on this since several days, but can't find a clue...

Comment: What CPU frequency scaling driver and governor are you using? Do: `cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_driver` and `cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_governor` and add it to your question. How do you know that the CPU frequency you are being told is the actual CPU frequency?

Comment: Hi Doug,thanks for answering. Well, acpi-cpufreq is the result from the first command and ondemand is the scaling governor. In addition the cpu freq is visibile from the conky utility. It looks like it has been set @ 1.99 GHz in idle and 2.88GHz when under stress, althoug the maximum frequency should be 3.33

Comment: Yes, but since you gave overclocked your processor, how to you know that what conky reports is actually the CPU frequency?

Comment: Because it is the same indication I got by other means I used via terminal.

Comment: The acpi-cpufreq driver reports the frequency that was asked for, which may not be the actual frequency. What I do as a sanity check is use a infinite loop program that prints every so many million loops, such that I can calculate if the reported frequency makes sense. In your case we do not know how to calibrate such a method. Does turbostat work on your processor? If so, it might give actual frequency numbers.